# Finding xpath of an element that appears for a very short amount of time

Tags: selenium, xpath, ui-automation

Is there a good method to find the xpath of an element that only appears very briefly (e.g. for a second or two, like a loading screen).

If I click within an application and a short loading screen appears I would like to find the xpath of the loading element so I can have selenium wait until the element is no longer on the page before continuing.

Sometimes the loading screen appears over the element I want to click and catches the click instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are struggling to find XPath of the element that quickly disappears from the page before you could inspect and find the xpath.

1. You can try opening the console in the webpage by using **Ctrl+Shift+I**.
2. Then navigate to the **Network** tab next to **console** tab
3. Below Network tab you will find **Online** dropdown.
4. Click on the arrow beside the online dropdown, you will find multiple options click on the one which says **Slowest** This will reduce the speed of your website loading and gain you more time to find the xpath.
   or 
   You can also customize the throttle by clicking on **add** option and providing Download, Upload and Latency. or you can directly choose **Offline** option once your loading icon is enabled.

[Attached screenshot for your reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06kPN.png)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below using web driver wait, not sure which programing language you are using butyou refer same concept with other languages too:

```
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'your text1')]")))
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```